# Shorter Parameter List with Defaults

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, reflection, entity-framework-core

Is their a way I can tidy this up

```
public Task<List<Categories>> GetAllCatgoriesViewModelAsyncByStoreId(Guid StoreId, Guid TenantId)
{
  return _context.Categories.Where(w => w.StoreId == StoreId && w.TenantId == TenantId).ToListAsync();
}
```

I know for where clauses I can do this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrder>().HasQueryFilter(q => q.isDeleted == false && q.isActive == true);           
modelBuilder.Entity<SalesOrderItem>().HasQueryFilter(q => q.isDeleted == false && q.isActive == true);
```

But it still means I have to do this every time (Guid StoreId, Guid TenantId) as below is their anyway to have a cleaner parameter List?

```
GetAllCatgoriesViewModelAsyncByStoreId(Guid StoreId, Guid TenantId)
```

//This version would still apply the above parameters but not having to create them each time both in the method signature and where clause

Something like .HasStoreTenantId

```
 public Task<List<Categories>> GetAllCatgoriesViewModelAsyncByStoreId()
 {
        return _context.Categories.HasStoreTenantId().ToListAsync();
 }
```

Comment: A extension method can be a good fit. This example can help you : [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Comment: I wonder if you can write an extension method for this. I would define an interface, that has `Guid StoreId,Guid TennantId` as properties. Then add this interface to the classes that must have it. You could then write an extension method, something like `static bool HasStoreTennantId(this Entity<T> e) where T : ITennantStore { ... }`